# How to obtain Amazon EC2 Spot Instance interruption rates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a script to get best prices for on-demand and also see spot prices for the same instances. https://github.com/fuatu/awsEC2pricefinder

This is what I give as an output below. I want to have another column for each instance and display the "Frequency of interruption".

```
(awspricing) ~/Projects/awspricing $ python awsEC2pricing.py -t 2 4
Records are up-to-date
--------------------------
 vCPU: 2.00
 RAM: 4.00
 OS: Linux
 Region: US East (N. Virginia)
--------------------------
Instance        vCPU   RAM    OS         PriceH   PriceM      SpotH    SpotM   
t3a.medium      2.00   4.00   Linux      0.03760  27.07200    0.01140  8.20800
t3.medium       2.00   4.00   Linux      0.04160  29.95200    0.01250  9.00000
t2.medium       2.00   4.00   Linux      0.04640  33.40800    0.01430  10.29600
a1.large        2.00   4.00   Linux      0.05100  36.72000    0.01990  14.32800
t3a.large       2.00   8.00   Linux      0.07520  54.14400    0.02260  16.27200
m6g.large       2.00   8.00   Linux      0.07700  55.44000    0.00000  0.00000
```

You can see "Frequency of interruption" percentages here: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/

I googled and also checked the boto3 ec2 methods and cannot find any option to get interruption rates. So any help to show how to get this data programmatically are welcome.

Comment: Hello, how to you look for all EC2 instances and just not the EBS Only one.

<code>{'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'storage', 'Value': 'EBS only'},</code>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution from a colleague.

This link has the interruption rates. 
https://spot-bid-advisor.s3.amazonaws.com/spot-advisor-data.json

I also updated my code accordingly

sample code here:

```py
def get_ec2_spot_interruption(instances=[], os=None, region=None) -> defaultdict(None):
    import requests
    import json
    results = defaultdict(None)
    url_interruptions = "https://spot-bid-advisor.s3.amazonaws.com/spot-advisor-data.json"
    try:
        response = requests.get(url=url_interruptions)
        spot_advisor = json.loads(response.text)['spot_advisor']
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return
    rates = {
        0: "<5%",
        1: "5-10%",
        2: "10-15%",
        3: "15-20%",
        4: ">20%"
    }
    for ii in instances:
        try:
            rate = spot_advisor[region][os][ii]['r']
            results[ii] = rates[rate]
        except KeyError:
            results[ii] = ""
    return results
```